# How to get date value from protected array?

Tags: php, arrays, date, amazon-mws

I am getting this output from Amazon's Report API and i am trying to get the AvailableDate field value but it keep telling me .

Output from Amazon API:

```
MarketplaceWebService_Model_ReportInfo Object
(
    [fields:protected] => Array
        (
            [ReportId] => Array
                (
                    [FieldValue] => 11111111111
                    [FieldType] => string
                )

            [ReportType] => Array
                (
                    [FieldValue] => _GET_DATE_RANGE_FINANCIAL_TRANSACTION_DATA_
                    [FieldType] => string
                )
            [ReportRequestId] => Array
                (
                    [FieldValue] => 11111111111
                    [FieldType] => string
                )
            [AvailableDate] => Array
                (
                    [FieldValue] => DateTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2014-11-07 11:50:58
                            [timezone_type] => 1
                            [timezone] => +00:00
                        )
                    [FieldType] => DateTime
                )
            [Acknowledged] => Array
                (
                    [FieldValue] => 
                    [FieldType] => bool
                )
            [AcknowledgedDate] => Array
                (
                    [FieldValue] => 
                    [FieldType] => DateTime
                )
        )
)
```

I am trying this code:

```
$sdate = new DateTime($available_date);
```

Please help...

Comment: it is not an array but an object .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the public `getAvailableDate()` method.

```
<?
$marketPlaceReport = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_ReportInfo();

$sdate = $marketPlaceReport->getAvailableDate();
?>
```